# mediaelements.js audio player need fix for mobile responsive sizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I really am impressed with this plugin and just have one issue that I can't seem to resolve or find a solid fix to on other forums.  I would like the audio player element in my posts to respond to device resizing as my current theme does for all the other visual elements.  The video player seems to be responding perfectly to resizing for moible, but the audio player runs off the side of the screen.  Any insight would be great. Here's the site for reference if needed:
http://ericbvoice.com/category/commercial/

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure it out in the meantime? When I open your links, the players behave responsively. I can't find the javascript code that achieves this? Or did you do it by modifying the CSS?
Best regards - Ulrich
Edit: Have figured out a solution now:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#audioplayer',
            { pauseOtherPlayers: false,
                features: ['playpause', 'current', 'progress', 'duration']
            });
            player.pause();
            player.play();
            var inPlayersize = 400;
            function resPlayer() {
                if ($(window).width() + 20 < inPlayersize) {
                    player.setPlayerSize($(window).width() - 20, 30);
                    player.setControlsSize();
                }
            }
            resPlayer();
            $(window).resize(function () {resPlayer();});
        });
```